# Proposition command doesn't work

Tags: theorems, thesis

Please refer to the below code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report} 
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\oddsidemargin 0.0in
\textwidth 6.27in
\topmargin -0.5in
\textheight 9.69in
\footskip 0.5in
\urlstyle{sf}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subfig}
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{prop}
1. $x=Y+z$ \\
2. $\alpha=1-x$
\end{prop}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you really don't need to load the packages `amsmath` and `amssymb` twice.  (order doesn't matter here, so just put them wherever you find easiest to remember.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to define the structure using `\newtheorem` (refer to the documentation of the `amsthm` package for further details on the optional arguments of this command):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}

\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}

\begin{document}
\begin{prop}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $x=Y+z$
\item $\alpha=1-x$
\end{enumerate}
\end{prop}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Not related to the question, but I replaced you manual enumeration with an `enumerate` environment. You are loading some packages more than once; this should be avoided. Also changes to the page layout should be better done using the `geometry` package.

Comment: How about for the lemmas. Let say i want to write a lemma

Comment: @Norman Same idea: in the preamble: `\newtheorem{lemm}{Lemma}`, and then in the document `\begin{lemm} contents\end{lemm}`.

Comment: And if you want the text to be upright, not italicized, you can always add `\theoremstyle{definition}\newtheorem{rant}{Angry Rant}`. More examples may be found in the [AMSthm documentation](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amscls/amsthdoc.pdf).

Comment: Seems that the a4wide package is no longer supported. You should use the geometry package. and give a4 as an option.
cheers

Comment: @GonzaloMedina  if i have a lemma with sections, As an example Lemma 1, Lemma 1.1 and Lemma 1.2  like wise, what would be the latex command?

Comment: @Norman Please don't use comments for follow-up questions. Feel free to open a fresh new question.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126139/lemmas-and-sub-sections