# Lemmas and sub sections

Tags: theorems, thesis

I want to write a `LaTeX` code to show,

```
Lemma 1 : x+y=z
Lemma 1.1:  z-r+t=3
Lemma 1.2:   q=r
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `amsthm` package

**Update:** per Gonzalo Medina's suggestion, using the following definition which make the sublemma counter subsidiary to the lemma counter:

```
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{sublemma}{Lemma}[lemma]
```

such that the following code:

```
\begin{lemma}
x+y=z
\end{lemma}
\begin{sublemma}
z-r+t=3
\end{sublemma}
\begin{sublemma}
q=r
\end{sublemma}

\begin{lemma}
x+y=z
\end{lemma}
\begin{sublemma}
z-r+t=3
\end{sublemma}
\begin{sublemma}
q=r
\end{sublemma}
```

will give you:

[image]

**EDIT:** If you want to number your theorem with correspondence to the section it belongs to, use these definition instead:

```
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{sublemma}{Lemma}[section]
```

Then check out the example:

```
\section{Math}
\begin{document}
\begin{lemma}
x+y=z
\end{lemma}
\begin{sublemma}
z-r+t=3
\end{sublemma}
\begin{sublemma}
q=r
\end{sublemma}

\section{More Math}
\begin{lemma}
x+y=z
\end{lemma}
\begin{sublemma}
z-r+t=3
\end{sublemma}
\begin{sublemma}
q=r
\end{sublemma}
```

which gives you:

[image]

Comment: Isn't it `\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}\newtheorem{sublemma}{Lemma}[lemma]` a better option?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Not if the author is not dividing his article into different sections. But you are right, I should've mentioned it.

Comment: What do sections have to do with my suggestion? I suggested making the `sublemma` counter subsidiary to the `lemma` counter (independently of sectional unit counter which can be taken into account when defining lemma, if necessary), which seems to be what the OP wants.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I misunderstood it, it is a better method :)

Comment: What if we wanted to not number the lemma, if we are only using one?

Answer (score 7):

Once yoy have defined your structure for lemmas using, for example

```
\newtheorem{lemm}{Lemma}
```

you can define a new structure `slemm` and make the counter for this new structure subsidiary to the `lemm` counter using the second optional argument for `\newtheorem`:

```
\newtheorem{slemm}{Lemma}[lemm]
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{lemm}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{slemm}{Lemma}[lemm]

\begin{document}

\begin{lemm}
test
\end{lemm}
\begin{slemm}
test
\end{slemm}
\begin{slemm}
test
\end{slemm}
\begin{lemm}
test
\end{lemm}
\begin{slemm}
test
\end{slemm}
\begin{slemm}
test
\end{slemm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For clarity sake, I would give another name to the subsidiary structure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{lemm}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{slemm}{Sublemma}[lemm]

\begin{document}

\begin{lemm}
test
\end{lemm}
\begin{slemm}
test
\end{slemm}
\begin{slemm}
test
\end{slemm}
\begin{lemm}
test
\end{lemm}
\begin{slemm}
test
\end{slemm}
\begin{slemm}
test
\end{slemm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\begin{document}
\section{One}
\begin{lem}
  one
\end{lem}
\begin{lem}
  one.two
\end{lem}
\section{Two}
\begin{lem}
  two
\end{lem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want to see the section number. I want to see without section number, just a increment

Comment: @Francis I don't want to see the section number, when I do like urs It will appear like this   Lemma 7. x+y=z and Lemma 1.2 r=q, 1.2 is the section number. I don't want to show that. It should be Lemma 7.1 not with the section number