# Numbering sublemmas

Tags: numbering, theorems, lemma

I would like to have sublemmas numbered after the corresponding lemmas, which in turn would be numbered after theorems, like this:

> Theorem 2.1. 0=0.
>
> Lemma 2.2. 0=1.
>
> The proof of Lemma 2.2 will be given later.
>
> Lemma 2.3. 1=1.
>
> Sublemma 2.2.1. 0=2.
>
> Proof: Obvious.
>
> Sublemma 2.2.2. 0=4.
>
> Proof: Obvious.
>
> Sublemma 2.3.1. 0=0.

Here Sublemma 2.2.1 and 2.2.2 are sublemmas of Lemma 2.2 (even though in the text they appear only after Lemma 2.3), and Sublemma 2.3.1 is a sublemma of Lemma 2.3.

I need this, because I would like to first present, in a series of lemmas, a general outline of the proof of a theorem, and then prove the lemmas via sublemmas, each of the daughter sublemmas clearly corresponding to its parent lemma.

Is this possible to do?

The solutions offered at [Lemmas and sub sections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126139/lemmas-and-sub-sections) do make "the sublemma counter subsidiary to the lemma counter". However, there the sublemmas of a lemma (say Lemma 5) must follow Lemma 5, with no other lemmas stated between Lemma 5 and its sublemmas.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following elementary, yet cumbersome solution. I'd still appreciate a better one.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}

\newcounter{sublOne}
\newenvironment{sublOne}[1][]{\refstepcounter{sublOne}\par\medskip
   \noindent \textbf{Sublemma~\ref{lem:1}.\thesublOne. #1} \rmfamily}{\medskip}

\newcounter{sublTwo}
\newenvironment{sublTwo}[1][]{\refstepcounter{sublTwo}\par\medskip
   \noindent \textbf{Sublemma~\ref{lem:2}.\thesublTwo. #1} \rmfamily}{\medskip}

\newcommand{\refs}[2]{\ref{#1}.\ref{#2}}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
\begin{thm} $0=0$. \end{thm}

------------------------------

\section{Second section}

\begin{thm} $1=1$. \end{thm}
\begin{lem}\label{lem:1} $2=2$ \end{lem}
\begin{lem}\label{lem:2} $3=3$ \end{lem}

\begin{sublOne}\label{subl:2.2.1} 
$2.1=2.1$. \end{sublOne}

\begin{sublOne}\label{subl:2.2.2} 
$2.2=2.2$. \end{sublOne}

\begin{sublTwo}\label{subl:2.1.3} 
$3.1=3.1$. \end{sublTwo}

Sublemmas~\refs{lem:1}{subl:2.2.1} and \refs{lem:1}{subl:2.2.2}  
are sublemmas of Lemma \ref{lem:1}, whereas Sublemma~\refs{lem:2}{subl:2.1.3}
is a sublemma of Lemma \ref{lem:2}.
```

producing this output:

[image]